# Howto parse csv and returns a dataSet as a result

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, parsing

I need a CSVParser class file 
A Class File which parses csv and returns a dataSet as a result ASP.Net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that [CSVReader](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx) (CodeProject) can read to `DataTable`.

```
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        // set up schema... (Columns.Add)
        using(TextReader text = File.OpenText(path))
        using(CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(text, hasHeaders)) {
            table.Load(csv);
        }
```

Note that manually setting up the schema is optional; if you don't, I believe it assumes that everything is `string`.

Answer (score 1):

Simple google gives plenty of [results](http://windowsclient.net/blogs/faqs/archive/2006/05/30/how-do-i-load-a-csv-file-into-a-datatable.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I've had luck with this [parser](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/GenericParser.aspx).  It will return results to a DataSet.

Another tool you might want to check out is [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/).  I see there's a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filehelpers) for this resource here on SO.